# My game keeps crashing saying " EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xb176e978) " when I run on my iPad

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, skspritenode

I am developing an app for iOS and I've run into a problem. Every time I run the app on my iPad with iOS 7.1 the app crashes at random times when the scene changes pointing to different SKSpriteNodes with the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xb176e978). the way I set my sprite nodes is by writing this:

```
var X = SKSPriteNode(imageNamed:"picture.png")
```

the entire game is written on Xcode with swift.

**EDIT:** I've noticed that the address=0xb176e978 isn't constant. it shows different address=' ' sometimes.

**THE SCENE CHANGING CODE**

```
var gameScene = EndScene(size: self.size)
gameScene.gameScene = self 
gameScene.score = score 
gameScene.highscore = highscore 
var transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill 
self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

Comment: Make sure there is an image set named "picture" in your `Images.xcassets` asset catalog. If this is the case, you do not need to specify the file extension, so remove ".png." Also, what error are you seeing in the console? If you scroll up a little bit in the console after your app breaks, you should get a more specific error message.

Comment: I added my pictures to the 'Images.xcassets' catalog and now it crashes more often. Also I can't scroll up when the app breaks, nothing comes up. I've also noticed that 'address=0xb176e978' part isn't constant, it sometimes gives a different address code.

Comment: I would check the scene loading code. Is it possible to provide a little more code? Also, is the game for iPad only?

Comment: The game is Universal so it's for all iDevices and the code I used for scene changing is ::::

`var gameScene = EndScene(size: self.size)

gameScene.gameScene = self

gameScene.score = score

gameScene.highscore = highscore

var transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)

gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)` 
this is the code I use from the game to the game-over scene. Although all my scene changing code are the same format

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint before the last line: `self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)`. Does it get that far when you run the code? If so, check the values of `self.scene!` and `self.scene!.view?` See if one of those optional variables is `nil`.

Comment: i'll put the scene changing code in the question, because it looks weird.

Comment: I added the breakpoints, and it does indeed get that far, however when I run the game without breakpoints, it goes to the game-over scene. The problem is that sometimes the game will crash when I try to restart the game, and other times it'll crash when I press the play button on the main menu.

Comment: how do I check if the values for `self.scene!` and `self.scene!.view?` are `nil` ?

Comment: In the console, type `po` then the variable name, and press the Return key. So you would type `po self.scene!` and then `po self.scene!.view?`. If you receive an error on the first one, it means that you are trying to unwrap a `nil` value.

Comment: ohh. no errors, it returns `po self.scene!` and `po self.scene!.view?`

Comment: I would try going through some standard debugging steps. If you know where the game is crashing, take out some lines of code until you find the line or lines that are causing the crash. Then figure out why those lines are causing the crash.

Comment: alright so I found the **prime** source of what (I hope) is causing the crashes. It's a spriteNode that is used as a restart button. I set it like: `var res = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restart")` and then I put `res.name = "goBack" ` ( so that I could use the node's name in the `touchesBegan` func ) is there anything you can help me with in this?

Comment: I don't know too much about `SKSpriteNodes`, but I feel that the name of the image is not matching up with the image asset. I'm not sure if setting the `name` property changes the image asset. Instead of `res.name = "goBack"`, try `res = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "goBack")`. Or you can use a separate variable in the `touchesBegan` function.

Comment: I fixed it, I just removed sprite that was giving me issues and replaced it! how do I give you good Karma for helping me?

Comment: Awesome! I can post an answer, but you ultimately solved it yourself! I would actually recommend that you post an answer and mark it as solved so others potentially looking at this in the future will know how you fixed it. And don't worry about the karma; I'm not after it :)

Comment: Oh you're right I'll be sure to do that, and just to make it clear...You the real MVP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why it was causing an issue, but one of my sprites from the last scene was causing the crash. I removed it and now it works fine.